# Unable to publish to a new deployment

Tags: deployment, google-app-maker

I am unable to publish to a new deployment. I get a Error 404. 404. That’s an error.

The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Could you please help me solve this issue?

Thanks,
Maria.

Answer (score 0):

Please check recent update from App Maker Team posted here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appmaker-users/XqBpaeDD2Lc

It seems like the data access infrastructure is having some troubles and the App Maker Team are working on it. Please check the above thread for updates. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Note: Please make sure you are using the following tag for future App Maker questions: appmaker

**UPDATE**: This should be fixed now, but please let us know if you still see any error during the preview / publishing process.